# pecl install sqlsrv FAILS with configure error: C compiler cannot create executables on SLES 12

Tags: sql-server, gcc, pear, pecl

I've been at my wits end with this for the past several hours trying to figure out what is going on. I am running a SLES 12 SP3 server and need to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database from PHP, I followed microsoft's documentation up to the point where it asks me to run this command:

```
pecl install sqlsrv
```

The command fails with the following relevant output:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootLa81RX/sqlsrv-5.3.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
rolling back 8 file operations
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

I would love to check config.log for more detailed error information, but it appears that everything in the /tmp/pear/temp directory gets deleted immediately after the failed attempt, including the log. In an attempt to diagnose the error I attempted to build the following C file using gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("hello world\n"); return 0; }
```

and got this equally weird error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

At this point I officially have no idea where to look to try to diagnose what is actually going on here.

Comment: Where did you get the GCC 8 installation? I thought the SLES SP3 Toolchain Module was still at GCC 7.

Comment: all I did was zypper install gcc

Comment: Did you update binutils as well?

Answer (score 0):

Relocation 0x2a is `R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX`, which is used for creating certain relaxable x86-64 relocations (relocations that can be optimized by the linker).  You will need at least binutils 2.26 to process these object files.